# Markdown no está funcionando en el Centro de Ayuda

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones

Algunos textos del centro de ayuda contienen MarkDown, que no se está interpretando a la hora de construir la página.

Ejemplo:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo que esto se corrigió. En [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) se ve un correcto:

> Stack Overflow es un sitio para profesionales y aficionados de la programación, personas que escriben código porque aman hacerlo. Creemos que [las mejores preguntas en Stack Overflow](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) tienen siempre un poco de código pero si tu pregunta es acerca de…